# how to include tab panel id between if statement

Tags: php, html

I have done some coding to display a table inside a tab panel which is password protected. After doing query if the given password exist or not I want to show that panel tab. I have written that inside if statement. Codes are executing,because there is an echo statement and it is displaying. but the tab panel is not showing.Please help!.
`

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">Private</a></li>
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['passwordprivate']))
            {
                $password="";
                $pass=$_POST['passwordprivate'];
                $q="select password_private from password where password_private='$pass'";
                $r=mysql_query($q);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
                $password=$row['password_private'];
                if($password)
                {
        ?>
    <a class="active" href="#tab2primary" data-toggle="tab"></a>
     <?php echo"<script language='javascript'>alert('ok')</script>";?>

    <?php
            }
            else
             {
                echo"<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid password')</script>";
                 }
            }
    ?>
```

Here is the sample of the code.

Comment: I just want to know how to declare the id of the tab '#tab2primary' inside the If statement

Comment: So does the `if` part show up, e.g. do you get an `ok` alert?

Comment: yes, i have got ok alert

Answer (score 0):

I could get that to show tab2. But now it is always in show state :(

```
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">Private</a></li>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['passwordprivate']))
    {
        $password="";
        $pass=$_POST['passwordprivate'];
        $q="select password_private from password where password_private='$pass'";
        $r=mysql_query($q);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
        $password=$row['password_private'];
        if($password)
        {
            ?>
            <?php 
            echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('ok'); ";
            //echo "$('.nav-tabs').removeClass('active');";
            //echo "$('.nav-tabs').addClass('hide');";
            //echo "$('.nav-tabs a[href=\"#tab2\"]').tab('show');";
            echo "$('.nav-tabs a[href=\"#tab2\"]').tab('show');";
            echo "</script>";
            ?>

            <?php
        }
        else
        {
             echo"<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid password')</script>";
             }
     }
    ?>
```